# I can not snap this two object precisely with direct selection tool also .What can I do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image][image: **enter image description here**][image][image]I am trying to make a table like structure but the object i.e. a line segment which will connect both top and bottom pieces is not snapping perfectly.What can i do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Is it a line ? Or is it expanded?

Comment: It is a line i did not expand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click on the line
- Switch to Direct Selection tool and click on the top anchor-point of the line
- Drag it over the other lines and it will snap to the other line's end

It should look like this:

[image]

### UPDATE

From your update id looks like the "line" is not a line. It looks more like you used the rectangle tool to create the line or something like it.

Please try to recreate the line and snap it like I suggested above or better yet, select the line tool and create the line directly from one anchor point to another! This has to work. There's nothing that can stand in it's way!

**Line** vs **Line like Rectangle** view:

[image]

Comment: It does not work like that i tried that !

Comment: @GauravPrachchhak See my updated answer.

Comment: Update : See above i did it again with line segment tool but then also the small piece would not stick to its place and snap to anchor point !

Comment: @GauravPrachchhak One last try, uncheck the Align to Pixel Grid and while dragging with the DIRECT SELECTION TOOL (the white one) Keep CTRL Pressed !

Comment: @GauravPrachchhak Phew =)) Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score -1):

Check "Align to Pixel Grid" in "transform" menu.

Comment: It is already checked !

Comment: This setting should be same for both objects.